# Passing URL params from one page to other

Tags: url, parameters

Get parameter from one page and update iframe and then pass it on to a third page part of link.

Page A --> Page B (part of iframe in Page A) --> Page C (invoked from a link in Page B)

All three pages on different domains. URL parameters need to be passed from Page A to Page C.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking.  What have you tried?  What kind of error(s) are you getting?

Comment: for example you have a web page
  
Page 1 --> www.examplepage1.com?param1=y&param2=z

The above page 1 is holding page 2 within iframe 

Page 2 --> www.otherpage2.com with a link to Page 3 --> www.anotherpage3.com

I need to append/pass the initial page1 parameters to Page3 as url parameters.